# Multitouch drag and drop android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, multi-touch

i want multitouch drag and drop in my android application.
my reequirment is when user uses two finger then only dragging should be done. with single figure no dragging.
how can i achieve this?
my code looks like this

```
      if (pointerCount == 2) {

            switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             //what should i write here?
                 break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
             //what should i write here?
```

what should i write for each event case.
any helpfullink??

Comment: try out these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818530/how-to-implement-a-two-finger-drag-gesture-on-android   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350064/android-how-to-handle-two-finger-touch